# HDD recognized as drive on computer, but doesn't allow for file exploration

Tags: hard-drive, ata

I've seen several other similar questions about the topic on this site, however none have helped me. I am posting this question in case there is an updated solution to the problem, or if somehow my problem is different from the others.

I have a WD internal hard drive for my custom build PC. It's been working fine for 3 years, until a week ago my windows 10 was corrupted. The problem here is that my SSD is the primary drive in the computer (that stores Windows) and not my HDD, so I didn't suspect it to be broken.

I tried transporting it home (because I have an ATA to USB bridge) and I thought I may have shorted it out on the drive home somehow. Now I'm at home, and when I connect it to my laptop (or any other computer for that matter) I hear windows recognizes my bridge, but the drive doesn't show up.

I tried changing USB ports, changing the letter of the drive (which doesn't work), making sure all the plugs were properly secured in the drive, and I tried other computers as well, nothing worked.

This post is my last ditch attempt at finding a solution, as my life's work is on that drive and I'd rather not pay $800 to a lab to extract it.

Comment: We would need to know the model of the HDD and of the ATA-USB bridge to determine if the bridge and drive are compatible.

Comment: The statement "I tried other computers as well, nothing worked" doesn't say the OSes nor the tools you used. Is there any chance you can connect the disk directly (only with ATA cable, without USB bridge) to some working PC? Does the BIOS/UEFI detect the disk then? Are you familiar with Linux (or are you willing to learn) enough to work with some live distro (e.g. Knoppix)? If so, the useful tools may be: if ATA cable then `lsblk`, `fdisk`/`gdisk`, `smartctl`; if USB bridge then additionally `dmesg`, `lsusb`. Later `ddrescue` maybe, but let's not skip so far ahead. Tell us what you can do.

Comment: Is ATA a typo for SATA?